# onChange Method Not Found in Dart

Tags: file-upload, dart, chromium

I'm trying to upload files using Dart and I've looked at this previous question to get a feel for what I need to do: [How to upload a file in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298140/how-to-upload-a-file-in-dart)

However, when I compile I'm getting the following error...

```
NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'onChange'
```

The following is the code that I used:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  InputElement uploadInput = query("#myFile");
  uploadInput.onChange.listen((e) {
    // read file content as dataURL
    final files = uploadInput.files;
    if (files.length == 1) {
      final file = files[0];
      final reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onLoad.listen((e) {
        sendData(reader.result);
      });
      reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
    }
  });
}

void sendData(dynamic data) {
  final req = new HttpRequest();
  req.onreadyStateChange.listen((Event e) {
    if (req.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE &&
        (req.status == 200 || req.status == 0)) {
      window.alert("upload complete");
    }
  });
  req.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/upload");
  req.send();
}
```

Am I missing an import or is Chromium not recognizing the File API?

Comment: Can you post the HTML for #myFile?

Comment: According to http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/InputElement.html#onChange, there is a `onChange`... Are you sure the `query` returns something?

Answer (score 1):

When a variable is `null` methods invoked on it throw `NoSuchMethodError`. So `uploadInput` should be `null` in your case because [onChange](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/InputElement.html#onChange) exists in the [InputElement](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/InputElement.html) class .