# How to upload file using FileUploadInputElement and HttpRequest.requestCrossOrigin()

Tags: dart, dart-io

I have a FileUploadInputElement in my dart code and I want to upload it by POST after button click. Can I sent files via HttpRequest.requestCrossOrigin()? 
I don't want to use form because it cause my page refresh.

```dart
ButtonElement uploadButton;

main(){
  .. 
  uploadButton.onClick.listen((e) => handleUpload(e));
  ..
}

handleUpload(Event e){
    List<File> files = uploadElement.files;

    HttpRequest.requestCrossOrigin(...);
}
```

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want to use `requestCrossOrigin` instead of `request`?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298140

Comment: Thanks your help! Any way can handle multiple upload?

Comment: No, haven't done this myself yet. As a start you can send the files one after the other. [How to upload a file in Dart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298140). The answer is rather old but the code seems right at the first glance. You have to change the events `on.xxx` to `onXxx` though.