# PUT request in Dart

Tags: dart, google-chrome-app, put

Does anyone know how to make a 'PUT' request in Dart?

I did this but then I don't know how to continue:

```
HttpRequest request =new HttpRequest();
request.open("PUT", url);
...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
var resp = await HttpRequest.request('http://someurl.com', 
    method: 'PUT', sendData: data);
// Do something with the response.
```

or

```
HttpRequest.request('http://someurl.com', 
    method: 'PUT', sendData: data)
.then((HttpRequest resp) {
  // Do something with the response.
});
```

Comment: How can I pass one or more files?

Comment: Sounds like a different question. Probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742113 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025084